# How to decrease clock frequency using only JK flipflops?

Tags: digital-logic, frequency, clock, flipflop

If I have a clock with frequency of 10 KHZ, how would I prove that by using only JK flipflops I can get another clock with frequency of 1250 HZ? What could a potential circuit and timing diagram look like?

Comment: The question is badly worded. You are not asked to increment the clock frequency but to REDUCE it from 10kHz to 1.25kHz, i.e., by a factor of eight. Please show some effort from yourself before you ask.

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Answer (score 3):

10Khz / 1250Hz = 8 = 2^3. meaning three flip-flops chained together.

Answer (score 3):

A JK Flip Flop can reduce clock frequency by 2 if you measure output Q.  Take that and feed it to another JK Flip Flop which will divide that frequency by 2 again.  A third one will do the trick.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMZ1Ep.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>